# Doing a push call using CURL in PHP to an api

Tags: php, html, ajax, api, curl

I am new to API calls

I need to do the following CURL call in PHP: Link to API Documentation http://dev.ducksboard.com/apidoc/tutorial/#overview

```
curl -v -u APIKEY:x -d '{"value": 10}' https://push.ducksboard.com/values/235
```

I have the following Updated Code(But not working):

```
 <?php


$postData = array('value' => 10);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://push.ducksboard.com/v/*****');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "000000000000000");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 

  $result=curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
  echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the values `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

```
$postData = array('value' => 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "APIKEY:0000000");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
```

also set `CURLOPT_POST` to `true`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Comment: Tried still now working, updated my code in the post if you can take a look

Comment: why do you have two `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData)); ` remove the first one

Answer (score 1):

The api wanted a password that was going to be ignored bellow is the working code

```
<?php


// encode the json object
$postData = json_encode(array('value' => 22));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://push.ducksboard.com/v/address');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "0000000000000000000000:IGNORED");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```